# Side in a Square Spiral In Python (Turtle Graphics)

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've created a program that generates a square spiral in Python using Turtle graphics.

What I am a little unsure about is the sides in the spiral.

What I have for my program currently is:

```
from turtle import *
startLength = int(input("Please enter the length of first side: "))
decrement = int(input("Please enter the change in length of side: "))
for i in range (3,8):
    startLength = startLength - decrement
    forward(startLength)
    left(90)
```

It works better when I can prompt the user to enter the number of sides like this:

```
from turtle import *
startLength = int(input("Please enter the length of first side: "))
decrement = int(input("Please enter the change in length of side: "))
sideNum = int(input("Please enter the number of sides: "))
for i in range (sideNum):
    startLength = startLength - decrement
    forward(startLength)
    left(90)
```

But I am only allowed to ask the user to enter the starting length and the decrement.

How can I create a spiral with correct number of sides without asking the user to enter the number of sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check to see how long the line would be and stop it when it gets too small, like:

```
from turtle import *
startLength = int(input("Please enter the length of first side: "))
decrement = int(input("Please enter the change in length of side: "))
while startLength > decrement:
    forward(startLength)
    left(90)
    startLength = startLength - decrement
forward(startLength)
```

That last `forward(startLength)` is to add that little remainder bit so that the spiral ends in the center. Also I put the `startLength = startLength - decrement` after drawing so that the first line is of length `startLength`.